# Google Visualization: Chart Editor Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I am try the Chart with a Google Visualization Chart when I click on OK nothing happens and the console displays the error:

> TypeError: a is not a function

The code I am using is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart', 'controls', 'charteditor'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
window.addEventListener('resize', redrawChart, false);

var chart;

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(GetData());

    var columnsTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    columnsTable.addColumn('number', 'colIndex');
    columnsTable.addColumn('string', 'colLabel');
    var initState = { selectedValues: [] };
    // put the columns into this data table (skip column 0)
    for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
        columnsTable.addRow([i, data.getColumnLabel(i)]);
        // you can comment out this next line if you want to have a default selection other than the whole list
        initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(i));
    }
    // you can set individual columns to be the default columns (instead of populating via the loop above) like this:
    // initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(4));

    chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'LineChart',
        containerId: 'chart_div',
        dataTable: data,
        options: {
            title: 'Number In Treatment'
        }
    });

    var chartEditor = new google.visualization.ChartEditor();
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chartEditor, 'ok', data);
    chartEditor.openDialog(chart, {});
    chart = chartEditor.getChartWrapper();
    redrawChart();

    var columnFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'filter_div',
        dataTable: columnsTable,
        options: {
            filterColumnLabel: 'colLabel',
            ui: {
                label: 'Columns',
                allowTyping: false,
                allowMultiple: true,
                allowNone: false,
                selectedValuesLayout: 'belowStacked'
            }
        },
        state: initState
    });

    var width = Math.min(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0) + 'px';

    chart.setOption('height', '200px');
    chart.setOption('width', width);

    setChartView();

    function setChartView() {
        var state = columnFilter.getState();
        var row;
        var view = {
            columns: [0]
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < state.selectedValues.length; i++) {
            row = columnsTable.getFilteredRows([{ column: 1, value: state.selectedValues[i] }])[0];
            view.columns.push(columnsTable.getValue(row, 0));
        }
        // sort the indices into their original order
        view.columns.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a - b);
        });
        chart.setView(view);
        chart.draw();
    }


    google.visualization.events.addListener(columnFilter, 'statechange', setChartView);

    setChartView();
    columnFilter.draw();
}

function redrawChart() {

    var width = Math.min(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0) + 'px';

    chart.setOption('height', '200px');
    chart.setOption('width', width);

    chart.draw();
}
```

How do I get the chart to be redrawn once the OK button has been clicked?

Comment: Try replacing the minified version of your google visualization libaray with the development version which will enable you to get a more descriptive error message.

Comment: what's the link for the development version of the google visualization library

Comment: Can you please update your post with you all your `<script>` inclusions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the last argument for the `'ok'` event, should be a reference to a callback function -- not `data`

see following snippet, `getWrapper` is passed as the callback
when it fires, use `getChartWrapper`

```
var chartEditor = new google.visualization.ChartEditor();
google.visualization.events.addListener(chartEditor, 'ok', getWrapper);
chartEditor.openDialog(chart, {});

function getWrapper() {
  chart = chartEditor.getChartWrapper();
  redrawChart();
}
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart', 'controls', 'charteditor']
});

var chart;

function drawChart() {
    var jsonData = "{\"cols\":[{\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"datetime\",\"type\":\"datetime\"},{\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"RPI1\",\"type\":\"number\"},{\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"RPI2\",\"type\":\"number\"}],\"rows\":[{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 40, 41)\"},{\"v\":\"22\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 40, 52)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 41, 2)\"},{\"v\":\"22\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 41, 12)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 41, 22)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 41, 32)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 41, 43)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 41, 53)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 42, 3)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 42, 13)\"},{\"v\":\"22\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 42, 23)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 42, 34)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 42, 44)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 42, 54)\"},{\"v\":\"19\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 43, 4)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 43, 15)\"},{\"v\":\"22\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 43, 25)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 43, 35)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 43, 45)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 43, 55)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 44, 6)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 44, 16)\"},{\"v\":\"19\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 44, 26)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 44, 36)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 44, 47)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 44, 57)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 45, 7)\"},{\"v\":\"19\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 45, 17)\"},{\"v\":\"20\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 45, 27)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 45, 38)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 45, 48)\"},{\"v\":\"21\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 45, 58)\"},{\"v\":\"23\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 46, 8)\"},{\"v\":\"23\"},{\"v\":null}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 46, 18)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"24\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 46, 29)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"22\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 46, 39)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"22\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 46, 49)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"21\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 46, 59)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"21\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 47, 10)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"22\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 47, 20)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"21\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 47, 30)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"21\"}]},{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Date(2017, 0, 3, 15, 47, 40)\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"22\"}]}]}"
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

    var columnsTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    columnsTable.addColumn('number', 'colIndex');
    columnsTable.addColumn('string', 'colLabel');
    var initState = { selectedValues: [] };
    // put the columns into this data table (skip column 0)
    for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
        columnsTable.addRow([i, data.getColumnLabel(i)]);
        // you can comment out this next line if you want to have a default selection other than the whole list
        initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(i));
    }
    // you can set individual columns to be the default columns (instead of populating via the loop above) like this:
    // initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(4));

    chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'LineChart',
        containerId: 'chart_div',
        dataTable: data,
        options: {
            title: 'Number In Treatment'
        }
    });

    var chartEditor = new google.visualization.ChartEditor();
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chartEditor, 'ok', getWrapper);
    chartEditor.openDialog(chart, {});

    function getWrapper() {
      chart = chartEditor.getChartWrapper();
      redrawChart();
    }

    var columnFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'filter_div',
        dataTable: columnsTable,
        options: {
            filterColumnLabel: 'colLabel',
            ui: {
                label: 'Columns',
                allowTyping: false,
                allowMultiple: true,
                allowNone: false,
                selectedValuesLayout: 'belowStacked'
            }
        },
        state: initState
    });

    var width = Math.min(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0) + 'px';

    chart.setOption('height', '200px');
    chart.setOption('width', width);

    setChartView();

    function setChartView() {
        var state = columnFilter.getState();
        var row;
        var view = {
            columns: [0]
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < state.selectedValues.length; i++) {
            row = columnsTable.getFilteredRows([{ column: 1, value: state.selectedValues[i] }])[0];
            view.columns.push(columnsTable.getValue(row, 0));
        }
        // sort the indices into their original order
        view.columns.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a - b);
        });
        chart.setView(view);
        chart.draw();
    }


    google.visualization.events.addListener(columnFilter, 'statechange', setChartView);

    setChartView();
    columnFilter.draw();
}

function redrawChart() {

    var width = Math.min(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0) + 'px';

    chart.setOption('height', '200px');
    chart.setOption('width', width);

    chart.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="filter_div"></div>
```

---

**note**: recommend using `https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js` to load the libraries, not `jsapi`

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the *jsapi* loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new *gstatic* loader from now on.

this will only change the `load` statement, see above snippet...